# Application crash on opening page containing Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have an app with a main page and one of the pages/activity off that should contain a map but when I click the button to open it my app crashes. How can I sort this ?

Manifest --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.edinburghnights1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <!-- You must insert your own Google Maps for Android API v2 key in here. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.edinburghnights1.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.edinburghnights1.Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

            </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="com.example.edinburghnights1.WhatsOn"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

           </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="com.example.edinburghnights1.ClubList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>

           </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

XML --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

  <fragment 

  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java --

```
package com.example.edinburghnights1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Map extends Activity{ // extends activity so it can be linked to rest of app


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                    setContentView(R.layout.mapsxml); //layout from mapsxml
                                    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back5); // name buttons to be used


                                      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                        public void onClick(View v) { //action when clicked
                                            Intent myintent2 = new Intent(Map.this,MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(myintent2);

                                        }
                                    });
                                    private void initilizeMap() {

                                        googleMap =   ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

                                          // check if map is created successfully or not

                                          }
        }}
```

Comment: Post your logcat here.

Comment: A stacktrace from the crash would probably be more useful than your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You should Change this

```
 googleMap =   ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

also need to extends your activity to `FragmentActivity` like:

```
  public class Map extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your cast of googleMap to SupportMapFragment

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```